# Azure AD Connect and Azure AD Connection Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to provision users from On Premise AD to Azure AD. The firewall within my organization blocks the provisioning process. I referred the following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-ports and referred the table 1, table 2, table 6a and 6b.

What this line states - For a list of URLs and IP addresses you need to open in your firewall, see Office 365 URLs and IP address ranges - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-365-urls-and-ip-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_portal_ip

In this URL, is it enough to raise firewall for the URLs under - Portal and shared FQDNs, Authentication and identity FQDNs.

Also there is one more link that displays Azure data center Ip ranges - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

What are these IPs mentioned in Azure data center. Should I need to raise for these as well?

I am really confused. Please any one help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> is it enough to raise firewall for the URLs under - Portal and shared
>   FQDNs, Authentication and identity FQDNs.

You are correct. That's all you need for AAD Connect to work.
You don't need the specific IP ranges. They are for the FQDNs listed under the page.